# Displaying Related List on Custom Object: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field

Tags: query, sobject, related-list

Any help would be greatly appreciated (either in actual code help or pointing me in the right direction).

I'm not much of a developer but was trying to get a related list from a custom object to display on another custom object. Basically I have a 'Bundled Products' object which has a products that are bundled together through a conjunction object ('Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c') connecting Bundled Products to Products. I want to display the related list of the conjunction object on another object which is 'Quote Bundles'. Right now I would be happy with just the Product Name but I am going to need more columns eventually.

The error that I am getting back on my page where I have dropped the visualforce at is 'Content cannot be displayed: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Quote_Bundle__c.Product_Bundle__r'.

I'm thinking this should be a simple fix but for the life of me I can't figure out what to do. Here is my class:

```
public class QuoteBundleClass {  

private List<Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c> pbpa;

private Quote_Bundle__c qb;

public QuoteBundleClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    this.qb = (Quote_Bundle__c)controller.getRecord();

    }    

    public List<Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c> getpbpa()

    {
        Quote_Bundle__c qbl = [Select id, Name, Product_Bundle__c, Product_Bundle__r.Id
                              From Quote_Bundle__c
                              Where id = :qb.Id];        

    if(qbl.Product_Bundle__c == null)
    return null;        
    pbpa = [SELECT Id, Product__r.Name, Name
            FROM Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c
            WHERE Product__r.Id = :qb.Product_Bundle__r.Id];
                     return pbpa;
    }
```

}

And here is my visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote_Bundle__c" extensions="QuoteBundleClass">      
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:detail relatedList="true"></apex:detail>
    <apex:pageblock id="CustomList" title="Bundled Products"  >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!pbpa}" var="p" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(pbpa))}">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:outputField value="{!p.Name}" />
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:outputLabel value="No records to display" rendered="{!(ISNULL(pbpa))}" styleClass="noRowsHeader"></apex:outputLabel>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
```

Thanks in advance guys and gals!

Comment: as an aside, I'd avoid returning null for getters with a return type of List<..>; instead, return empty lists

Comment: FYI, any answer may involve the fact that we are trying to retrieve a product list. It seems like this is a part of the answer. Let me know any background or answer if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this a few different ways and figured out I might not have been ensuring that the Product_Bundle__r.Id was the same as the Quote_Bundle__c.Product_Bundle__r.Id. I also had some issues with the Visualforce page using the related list and followed the [Salesforce Visualforce Related List guide.](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003207)

Below is my code. Let me know if you all have any questions.

```
public class QuoteBundleClass {  

private List<Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c> pbpa;

private Quote_Bundle__c qb;

public QuoteBundleClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    this.qb = (Quote_Bundle__c)controller.getRecord();
    }    

 public List<Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c> getpbpa() 

{
 Quote_Bundle__c qbl = [Select id, Name, Product_Bundle__r.Id
                        From Quote_Bundle__c
                        Where id = :qb.Id];        

if (qbl.Product_Bundle__c == null) {
    return null;        
}

pbpa = [SELECT Id, Name, Product_Bundle__r.Id
        FROM Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c
        WHERE Product_Bundle__r.Id = :qbl.Product_Bundle__r.id];
return pbpa;
}
}
```

And here is the visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote_Bundle__c" extensions="QuoteBundleClass">      
<apex:pageBlock title="Products">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!pbpa}" var="p" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(pbpa))}">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:outputField value="{!p.Name}" />
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    <apex:outputLabel value="No records to display" rendered="{!(ISNULL(pbpa))}" styleClass="noRowsHeader"></apex:outputLabel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do, rewrite your method with this:

```
public List<Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c> getpbpa() 
{
    if (qb.Product_Bundle__c == null) {
      return null;        
    }

    pbpa = [SELECT Id, Product__r.Name, Name
            FROM Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c
            WHERE Product__r.Id = :qb.Product_Bundle__c];

    return pbpa;
}
```

If that fails with a similar error then you can add the field `Product_Bundle__c` to the page layout and that should fix it. (Note: The field `Product_Bundle__c` is identical to `Product_Bundle__r.Id`, so there is no need to use both)

If it doesn't work, you have yet another thing to try (see below), but I think the first snippet alone will do it.

```
public List<Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c> getpbpa() 
{
     Quote_Bundle__c qbl = [Select id, Name, Product_Bundle__c
                              From Quote_Bundle__c
                              Where id = :qb.Id];        

    if (qbl.Product_Bundle__c == null) {
      return null;        
    }

    pbpa = [SELECT Id, Product__r.Name, Name
            FROM Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c
            WHERE Product__r.Id = :qb1.Product_Bundle__c];

    return pbpa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use code to accomplish this? You can do this quite easily in a declarative way after creating a second junction object called Quote Bundle_Product_Association__c with MD relationships to Quote Bundle and Products. Here are some links to help out:

1. [Help File for Many-to-Many Relationships](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_manytomany.htm)
2. [Walkthrough on creating Many-to-Many Relationships with Related List placement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_relationships_many_relationship.htm)

Comment: You can't do a MD relationship with Products. I am only doing lookup relationships. Do you think this would still be accomplish able through this method?

Comment: I didn't realize that when I posted. This won't work as advertised with the product table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your schema correctly, you have

```
Quote_Bundle__c with lookup to Product_Bundle__c
Product_Bundle__c is parent of Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c
Product_Bundle_Products_Association is child of Product2
```

So, the related list you need to return is given by:

```
public Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c[] getPbpa() {
   return this.qb.product_bundle__c == null
       ? new List<Product_Bundle_Products_Association__c> ()
       : [select id, 
            (select id, product__r.name, product_r.otherProductFldX__c, ...
                from Product_Bundle_Products_Associations__r)
           from Product_Bundle__c
           where id = :this.qb.product_bundle__c].product_bundle_Product_associations__r;
}
```

and your VF page fragment is:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!pbpa}" var="p" rendered="{!pbpa.size>0}">
    <apex:column>
       <apex:outputField value="{!p.product__r.name}" />
    </apex:column>
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
 <apex:outputLabel value="No records to display" rendered="{!pbpa.size=0}" styleClass="noRowsHeader"></apex:outputLabel>
```